# How do I make bootstrap tree view collapse from parent to child?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used Jon Miles's bootstrap tree view in my web application , but the parent is not collapsing to display the child. I'm sure I imported it correctly. What I'm trying to do is display parent and it collapses into different children. However, there's no collapse prompt to display children.

```js
var listTree = [{
    text: "Parent 1",
    nodes: [{
        text: "Child 1",
        nodes: [{
            text: "Grandchild 1"
          },
          {
            text: "Grandchild 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 2"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 3"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 4"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 5"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 6"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 7"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 8"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 9"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 10"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 11"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 12"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 13"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 14"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 15"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 16"
  }
];

$('#tree').treeview({
  data: listTree
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js " integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js" integrity="sha512-Hyk+1XSRfagqzuSHE8M856g295mX1i5rfSV5yRugcYFlvQiE3BKgg5oFRfX45s7I8qzMYFa8gbFy9xMFbX7Lqw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css" integrity="sha512-A81ejcgve91dAWmCGseS60zjrAdohm7PTcAjjiDWtw3Tcj91PNMa1gJ/ImrhG+DbT5V+JQ5r26KT5+kgdVTb5w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="./app.js "></script>

<div class="col-2 card m-1" id="product-list">
  <input type="search" name="product-search-list" id="product-search-list" placeholder="البحث" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="rating mt-2 text-center m-auto">
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  </div>
  <div id="tree">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [collapseIcon](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview#collapseicon) and [expandIcon](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview#expandicon) to set icon for expanding and collapsing of nodes .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var listTree = [{
    text: "Parent 1",
    nodes: [{
        text: "Child 1",
        nodes: [{
            text: "Grandchild 1"
          },
          {
            text: "Grandchild 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 2"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 3"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 4"
  }
];

$('#tree').treeview({
  data: listTree,
  collapseIcon: 'fas fa-minus', //added icon for expand and collapse
  expandIcon: 'fas fa-plus'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js " integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js" integrity="sha512-Hyk+1XSRfagqzuSHE8M856g295mX1i5rfSV5yRugcYFlvQiE3BKgg5oFRfX45s7I8qzMYFa8gbFy9xMFbX7Lqw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css" integrity="sha512-A81ejcgve91dAWmCGseS60zjrAdohm7PTcAjjiDWtw3Tcj91PNMa1gJ/ImrhG+DbT5V+JQ5r26KT5+kgdVTb5w==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="./app.js "></script>

<div class="col-2 card m-1" id="product-list">
  <input type="search" name="product-search-list" id="product-search-list" placeholder="البحث" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="rating mt-2 text-center m-auto">
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  </div>
  <div id="tree">

  </div>
</div>
```